# A difficulty in understanding a solution of an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals

The question and the solution are given in the following quotes:

> 2. Determine which of the following functions are in $L_2[0,1]$, then compute their norms.
>
> (a)  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$
>
> (b) $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\cos{at}}$, $a \in \mathbb R$
>
> (c) $\frac{1}{t^a}$, $a \in \mathbb R$
>
> (d) $t^n e^{at}$, $a \in \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb N$

Solution: (c). Proof:

> $\int_{[0,1]}\lvert{\frac{1}{t^a}}\rvert^2 = \int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{t^{2a}}$. If $2a \lt 1$, the improper Riemann integral exists and is absolutely convergent. Thus, $f(t)$ is also Lebesgue integrable and $\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{t^{2a}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^{2a}} = \frac{t^{1-2a}}{1-2a}\rvert_0^1 = \frac1{1-2a} \lt \infty$, which implies that $\int_{[0,1]}\lvert{\frac{1}{t^a}}\rvert^2 = \infty$. Thus, $\frac1{t^a} \in L_2[0,1]$ iff $a \lt \frac12$.

But I did not understand why the improper Riemann integral exists and is absolutely convergent. When $2a \lt 1$, and if $2a \geq 1$, why is it divergent?

Also, I did not understand how the author concluded that $f(t)$ is also Lebesgue integrable. Could anyone tell me which rule the author used to show this?

Comment: [See here](https://diversity.umn.edu/multicultural/sites/diversity.umn.edu.multicultural/files/p-test_000.pdf). It's called the 'integral p-test' or just 'p-test'. Note that if, say, $2 \alpha \le 0$ then the integrand is just a polynomial in $t$ which is integrable on a finite set.

Comment: And why he concluded that $f(t)$ is Lebesgue integrable? @Mattos